# How to Fetch multiple data with have same column?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch data with having the same column value. Like if I have 4 have a column which of them are the same like 1 kg=row(1) and 1 kg from row(2). so what I need is it should come in drop down once like only 1 kg and when I click it should fetch both. I am trying but didn't get any solution.

but when i am doing it is showing both values in dropdown.

**Here is where I need one value but when I click it should fetch both 1kg and same for others.**
[SEE PROBLEM IN IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEroG.png)

### **HERE IS CODE**

```
$qry2="select sizcod,sizcat 
        from tbsize 
        where sizcakcod IN ($array) ";
//if query does not work- do it maanually/union select sizcod,sizcat from tbsize where sizcakcod=3 union select sizcod,sizcat from tbsize where sizcakcod=5

$res2= mysqli_query($link, $qry2) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$out[]="<select name=s1 onchange=Getcakcod(this.value)>";
$out[]="<option value=-2>Select Size</option>";
while($siz_cake=mysqli_fetch_array($res2))
{

  //  echo $siz_cake[0];
   if(isset($_SESSION["sizcod"])&&$_SESSION["sizcod"]==$siz_cake[0])
   {
       $out[]="<option value=$siz_cake[sizcod] selected>$_siz_cake[sizcat]</option>";
   }
   else
   {
       $out[]="<option value=$siz_cake[sizcod]>$siz_cake[sizcat]</option>";
   }
```

Comment: Use DISTINCT in your query.

Comment: Please can you give me some more details. i am doing this but giving same value.

Comment: Your SQL query should be. `SELECT DISTINCT sizcod,sizcat FROM tbsize WHERE sizcakcod IN ($array)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches.

```
select distinct(sizecod),sizcat 
        from tbsize 
        where sizcakcod IN ($array) 


select sizecod,sizcat 
        from tbsize 
        where sizcakcod IN ($array) 
        group by sizecod
```

Pick the one that fits best for you. Both of them will return 1 row based on the sizecod value.

Comment: I have 2 rows that having 1 kg  and 1kg cake but both cake name is differrent but what i want is get the dropdown and select size which i want only 1 kg and then it should fetch that column which is having 1kg cake.